# Parsing through balanced parenthesis and obtaining corresponding elements

Tags: arrays, list, python-2.7, io, parentheses

I've to basically deal with a **balanced parentheses** like problem, but with a slight variation.
I need to read a file that looks like this (only 2 lines in a file):

```
aguuguuagucuacguggaccgacaagaacaguuucgaaucggaagcuugcuuaacguaguucuaacaguuuuuuauuag agagcagaucucugaugaacaaccaacgaaaaaagacgggucgaccgucuuucaauaugcugaaac
...((((((.((((((...((((...(((....)))...)))(((....))).))))))..)))))).........((((((.....))))))..................(((((((.....))))))).................
```

As you can see every letter has a corresponding "(" or ")" or "." associated with it, all the parenthesis are balanced but they are nested. As with a formula, each "(" and ")" means that there is a pair with the corresponding alphabets at the top.

**For eg: if a "(" has the alphabet "a" above it and the corresponding ")" {which makes it balanced} has a "u" above it, means that there is a "a"-"u" pairing. The "." means that those alphabets have no pairing. in this way i need to create an entire mapping of all the pairs and write it to a new file.**

In all the cases, "a" is paired with "u" and "g" is paired with "c".

I'm thinking of breaking this down into smaller chunks of balanced parenthesis and convert it into arrays but I'm finding it difficult to parse both the lines at the same time. Though i've written programs for checking balanced parenthesis before but i can't seem to come up with a logic to map each parenthesis to an alphabet above and pair it with the alphabet of the corresponding parenthesis.

Would really be grateful if someone could help me with a rough outline on this as I'm really not making any substantial progress.

EDIT: I need the output for each set of balanced parenthesis to look like this:

```
Input: gaacaguuuc
       (((....)))

Output: cagu have no pairs //because they have dots underneath
        g-c 
        a-u
        a-u
```

Comment: i would start with creating nodes to parse instead of strings. From your description, the two lines form a list of `[.()][acgu]` nodes. your task is then to parse the list of nodes. If I get it right, you can skip the . positions, so that the result has only paranthesis and letters in the nodes.

Comment: Can you show a short example output file for a shortened version of input.

Comment: @Mike i've included the Sample i/o.

Comment: @thst, Thanks for the advice. I need the output to contain information about the "." as well. Is there any chance i can break the problem into smaller modules, { smaller chunks- like the sample input } and then pair the alphabets.

Comment: you only dump the . parts. So they can be collected and removed from parsing the paranthesis. Did you alteady write non-functioning code? you should provide what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure not a py wizz. But this is my solution to your problem, as I understood it.

```
inp1 = "agucagcguagcugaucguga"
inp2 = "(..(((...(()).)...)))"

bkts = []
nomatch = []
pairs = []

for idx in range(len(inp2)):
    c = inp2[idx];
    if c == '(':
        bkts.append(inp1[idx])
    elif c == '.':
        nomatch.append(inp1[idx])
    elif c == ')':
        if len(bkts) > 0:
            pair = [bkts.pop(), inp1[idx]]
            pairs.append('-'.join(pair))
        else :
            print "error: Too many closing bkts"

if len(bkts) > 0 :
    print "Unmatched brackets! Too many open"

print "unmatched: " + ','.join(nomatch)
print "matches: " + ','.join(pairs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the outline, it solves the parsing problem I had.